# Consulta doble con php y msql

Tags: php, mysql, select

Gusto el saludarlos espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo la siguiente consulta que deseo hacer a mi base de datos:

Quiero hacer una doble condicion para obtener el resultado en numero de los registros de lo siguiente

Mostrar de la columna nombre todos los nombres del rango de fecha 01-01-2020 al 10-01-2020

mi consulta es la siguiente y quiero obtener el resultado solo que me no puedo generlarla

```
 $inicio="2020-09-01";
    $fin="2020-09-10";
    $varr="Ernesto";
    $sql="SELECT (*) from cliente  WHERE NOMBRE  = '$varr' &  FECHA BETWEEN '$inicio' AND '$fin' ";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    $ig = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo $ig ;
```

Gracias por el apoyo!

Comment: Tu columna fecha que tipo de dato es?, Además dices que quieres los nombres pero veo que haces un conteo, podrías explicar mejor?

Comment: Tienes un `&` simple, en lugar de `&&` o `AND`. Al colocarlo sencillo, se trata de un [operador a nivel de bits](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_a_nivel_de_bits) y no del operador lógico `AND`. Consulta [Operadores MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/non-typed-operators.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias asi es ya logre resolverlo  en lugar de & era el and para que ejecutara la consulta , pero muchas gracias!